# type 'null' is not a subtype of 'string' While trying to create a ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview

Hello everyone I'm making an app that will insert string values from a List to listView, however when I tried to run the code I got an error saying type `'null' is not a subtype of 'string' While trying to create a ListView in Flutter` but the error go away after I perform hot reload.

This is the Widget function `setupFileList` that will initialize listView

```
Widget setupFileList(BuildContext context) {
  var  mainReturn;
  var _showList = SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.separated(
              //physics: ScrollPhysics(parent: null),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1,color: Color.fromARGB(255,48, 48, 48)),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int _index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                child: Container(              
                  color: setupMainTheme,
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                        //
                    },

                    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right,color: Colors.grey),
                    title: Text(Text(_titleValues[_index],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(213, 255, 255, 255),
                      )),
                    subtitle: Text("Sub 1",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(197, 255, 255, 255),
                        fontSize: 12.8)),
                    }
                  )
                )
              );
              },
            itemCount: _titleValues.length,
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );

  if(_titleValues.length > 0) {
    mainReturn = _showList;
  } else {
    mainReturn = redundaneShow();
  }

  return mainReturn;
}
```

This is a widget function `redudaneShow` that will alerts user when there's no item on the list by putting text "It's empty here..." on the screen

```
Widget redundaneShow() {
    return Center(
      child: Visibility(
        visible: _isEmpty,
        child: Text(  
          "It's empty here..",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color.fromARGB(248, 94, 93, 93),
              fontSize: 26
          ),
        )
      )
    );
}
```

And this is the main class that will start showing the listView with `_titleValues` elements on it as soon the program starts and if the `_titleValues` is empty it will shows "It's empty here.." text (`redudaneShow`) function on the screeen instead

```
const setupMainTheme = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 18, 18);
const setupFontCol = Color.fromARGB(255, 83, 6, 172);
const setupThemeBar = Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 27, 27);
List<String> _titleValues = <String>["Something","something 2"];

class _cakeHomeWidgetState extends State<cakeWidget> { //State<cakeWidget>

  BuildContext? dialogContext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: setupMainTheme,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(58),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          title: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
             Text("☀️ Good morning",
                style: 
                  TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 190, 190),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 20
                    )
                ),
            ], 
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: setupMainTheme,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(12)),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    body: setupFileList(context),
      },
    ),
   );
  }
}
```

When I use debugger it tells me that the error occurs on `cakeWidget` (main class) but provides no details.

Comment: If you try to insert null into your list, you will get that error. Try declaring your list as List<String?> instead of List<String>

Comment: _titleValues[_index] check value is null or not... you can use _titleValues[_index].toString

Comment: Declaring List<String>? and _titleValues[_index].toString() solved my issue thanks.